# Why does the following not throw a syntax error in Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The following code in Chrome's Developer Console

```
}{
```

Evaluates as

```
undefined
```

Where it should throw a SyntaxError

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Other examples are

```
} + { //returns NaN
} + 1 + { //returns "1[object Object]"
```